# Handling pointer in vector C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Having problem using the vector in C++.
The following code is having this **Runtime Error :**

*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001e5d050 ***
=== Backtrace: ===
.
.
.

I have written this code.

```
    int main(){
    vector<int> ve; 
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++)ve.push_back(i);
    int last, sec_last, ans; 
    while(!(ve.empty())){
        ans = ve.back();  
        last = ve.back(); 
        ve.pop_back();
        sec_last = ve.back();
        ve.pop_back();
        ve.push_back(last + sec_last + last*sec_last);
    }
    cout<<"\nline 20\n";
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
    cout<<"\nline 22\n";

    }
```

Please explain me what does this error mean, and how can I correct it...

Comment: Step through in a debugger and examine variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Calling back / pop_back on an empty container is undefined" -- Internet

While loop condition prevents you only once, until the vector `ve` is modified again by `pop_back`. In that case there is possibility that vector is empty and calling `back` on empty vector will likely result into a crash.

```
  while(!(ve.empty())){
        ans = ve.back();  
        last = ve.back(); 
        ve.pop_back();        // <---- Vector could become empty
        sec_last = ve.back(); // <---- If vector is indeed empty, then undefined behavior
        ve.pop_back();
        ve.push_back(last + sec_last + last*sec_last);
    }
```